# Find the cheapest value in graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum

I have an undirected, weighted graph given with n nodes and m edges. In this graph it is possible to start at a node and visit all other nodes exactly once and return to the starting node (this may be not important). I need to pick n / 2 (n is even) edges such that every node is connected by only one edge and the sum of edges is minimal possible. One more thing should be satisfied, edges should not intersect between themselves.

I've tried brute force and it's too slow. I am not very familiar with graph theory, so maybe there exists some algorithm for this. What I'm looking for is a hint (or web link) to the algorithm that solves this problem.

Comment: Visiting each node exactly once and returning to the start is known as a [Hamiltonian cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) and finding Hamiltonian cycles is a very hard problem. [See also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem).

Comment: How is intersection defined? Is the graph a topological graph?

Comment: "every node is connected by only one edge and the sum of edges is minimal possible." It seems like [Minimum Spanning Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree).